# Cómo registrar/crear un "extended user" de django?

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Estoy trabajando con Django Rest Framework y creé un usuario que extiende de la clase User de django.

models.py:

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    es_tecnico = models.BooleanField(name = 'es_tecnico', default = False, blank = True)
```

Ahora bien, mi vista "Registrar" recibe un json a través de un POST que contiene los datos con los que crearé el usuario.

views.py:

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #  Creando un nuevo usuario
        username = request.POST.get('user.username')
        password = request.POST.get('user.password')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
        user.save()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return Response({'detail': 'El usuario fue creado con el token: ' + token.key})
```

Mi problema es que a la vez, cuando creo el User de django, necesito tamibén crear mi usuario extendido, el post recibe los datos del siguiente json:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "",
        "password": ""
    },
    "es_tecnico": false
}
```

Ahora necesito crear un Usuario con ese User, intenté algo como esto pero no funciona pero da a entender la idea:

views.py:

```
class Registrar(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UsuarioSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #  Creando un nuevo usuario
        username = request.POST.get('user.username')
        password = request.POST.get('user.password')

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, password)
        user.save()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        es_tecnico = request.POST.get('es_tecnico')
        usuario = Usuario.objects.create(user, es_tecnico)

        return Response({'detail': 'El usuario fue creado con el token: ' + token.key})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré este tutorial muy útil

https://wsvincent.com/django-rest-framework-authentication-tutorial/

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer] ya que esta publicación fue reportada como de "baja calidad", ¿De que forma ayuda a resolver el problema planteado en la pregunta?, agrega la información esencial del enlace,  saludos.